# Realtime Google Annotated Timeline

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a annotated timeline setup using the Google Visualization API (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#annotated_time_line).

The data source it is using is a MySQL database that is updated every minute. I'd like the graph to update every minute. I can do this easily by simply reloading the graph, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it without reloading the graph (i.e. the line simply shifts without redrawing the axes).

I know this is possible in something like FusionCharts but I'm not sure about Google Visualizations and I can't seem to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. 
set "allowRedraw" option to true for the updates and use draw(data,options) function to redraw the timeline.

I hope this helps.
Alper.